# Shaperenderer circle line width

Tags: libgdx

Is there any way to increase the width of the line that makes up the shaperenderers circle?

```
shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
shape.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
shape.setColor(1, 0.53f, 0.53f, 1);

shape.circle(nest.getCenter().x, nest.getCenter().y, radius, 500);
```

If not, is there any other approach that can give a similar effect?

Comment: I don't know much about libGDX, however, you could draw multiple circles at varying radius (same position), and thicken the line in a non-efficient manner.

Comment: Yeah That was kinda plan B :D haha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the OpenGL line width.

```
Gdx.gl.glLineWidth(32); // Or whatever thickness you need

// Then render the lines or circles as per what you're currently doing 
shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
shape.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
shape.setColor(1, 0.53f, 0.53f, 1);

shape.circle(nest.getCenter().x, nest.getCenter().y, radius, 500);
```